# stack test -- How to stop after first failure?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How do I get `stack test` to stop after the first failure of a test?

This would help with TDD where you expect many failures from the start and want to prevent lots of scrolling.

Comment: Which library are you using? `stack test` doesn’t actually do any testing itself; the tests are run by the library you are using for the tests.